# How to open docx with password in windows by COM in php?

Tags: php, window, ms-office

I have a docx file and know the password.

How can I pass the password as parameter to open it via COM object?

That is, I want it to operate in background.

Here is my code:

```
        $word = new COM("Word.Application");
        $word->Visible = 0;//set 0 to operate it at background
        $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;

        if(file_exists ($document))
        {
            $word->Documents->Open($document);
            return $word;
        }
        else
            return false;
```

Once the file is encrypted, office would open and ask me to enter the password.

I had tried [this ppt](http://www.slideshare.net/wezfurlong/php-and-com) , that is,

```
$word = new COM("Word.Application", 
                array( 'Server' => '127.0.0.1', 
                       'Username' => 'foo', 
                       'Password' => 'bar' ), 
                CP_UTF8);
```

However, it doesn't work.

Office still open and ask me the password.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally, I use Windows server as converter and linux server as DB.